# Getting country code (ISO-3166-alpha2 standard) for iOS >= 16 after deprecated Locale.isoRegionCodes API?

Tags: ios, swift, locale, iso-3166

We are facing the following issue with the following API `Locale.isoRegionCodes` which has been deprecated from iOS >= 16. The new API is the following `Locale.Region.isoRegions` but when doing a mapping like the following the `region.identifier` returns the code 001.

```
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            
           let CountryCodeWithNewApi = Locale.Region.isoRegions.map { region in
                CustomCountry(value: "", key: region.identifier)
            }.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
            
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

How do we get the old country codes of 2 letters by deriving it from this code? is it possible or we are required to do a manual mapping of the ISO-3166-alpha 2 codes to be able to display all the country codes to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
Locale.Region.isoRegions.filter { $0.subRegions.isEmpty }.map { $0.identifier }
```

gives the same list as the deprecated:

```
Locale.isRegionCodes
```

The following code:

```swift
let oldCodes = Locale.isoRegionCodes.sorted()
let newCodes = Locale.Region.isoRegions.filter { $0.subRegions.isEmpty }.map { $0.identifier }.sorted()
print(oldCodes == newCodes)
```

prints:

> true

when run on a macOS Swift Playground in Xcode 15.2 under macOS 14.3.1. It should also be true under iOS (but I haven't confirmed).

Your code then becomes something like the following:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    let countries = Locale.Region.isoRegions.compactMap {
        $0.subRegions.isEmpty ? CustomCountry(value: "", key: $0.identifier) : nil
    }.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
} else {
    let countries = Locale.isoRegionCodes.map { CustomCountry(value: "", key: $0) }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `compactMap { $0.subRegions.isEmpty ? nil : $0.identifier }` should avoid one loop (as `filter()` and `map()` iterates each one).

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow it seems it returns the same list as the old API; 256 elements of country codes in total. Just curious, where did you understood from the docs that the Regions Elements which doesn't have any subregions would represent the old API country code Regions? I have read the docs from top to bottom and didn't find any clue about this, did you just debugged deeply to see how the API was built under the hood?

Comment: @Coder I figured it out via intuition and testing. The regions list includes items such as "world", "north america", "eastern europe", etc. Those regions have subregions. It's only actual countries that don't have subregions. That was confirmed with the code I posted in the answer. The line `print(oldCodes == newCodes)` showing `true` proves the two lists are identical and have the same countries.

Comment: @HangarRash i discarded that intuition because by definition of what a region is, the Country Italy for example is divided in 20 regions. But i think Apple divided the globe in subregions based on their different languages, so for example in Italy the language would be the same as italian while each regions has its own latin language.

Comment: Regardless, the solution I posted works for your needs.